# Unable to run a simple hello world

Tags: java

I have this simple app:

```
package default1;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World333!");
  }
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
$ default1$ javac HelloWorld.java
$ default1$ java HelloWorld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: default1/HelloWorld)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

And this doesn't work either:

```
$ default1$ java default1.HelloWorld
Error: Could not find or load main class default1.HelloWorld
```

How to fix it? I've tried to do different thing and couldn't find the way to fix it.

Comment: Come out from the `default1` package folder and then run `$java default1.HelloWorld`

Comment: @AVD, thanks. why is that?

Comment: @imatahi The package name should be the same name as the class containing the main method (main class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

javac and java commands care about directory structure; package hierarchy and directory structure need to correspond to each other. In your case, change directory to the one that contains default1 directory and run:

```
javac default1/HelloWorld.java
java default1.HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making the package name the same as the name of the main class.

In this case, you can change `package default1;` to `package helloworld;`